# Applying a function containing tweens using a string actionscript3

Tags: flash, air, actionscript-3

Here is my scenario:

I have 5 vocabulary words on the left of my stage.  When the game begins, the first word moves into place on the right side of the screen.  At this point, the player can click a "next button" that I have on the bottom of the stage.  When this button is clicked, the second vocabulary word should animate into place on the right side of the stage while the first vocabulary word animates back into its original position on the left side of the stage.

All of the vocabulary words will use the same animation to move in and out of position.  I have pasted a portion of the code that I am trying to fix below.  This is only for the step that involves animating the next vocabulary word into place on the right side of the screen.  Im pretty sure if I can get help with this, I can figure out everything else on my own.

Hopefully the way that my incorrect code is set up will give a gist of what I am trying to accomplish.  The error I am getting is: : Error #1006: value is not a function. on the line: "`object2[animateIn]();`"

```
var animateIn:String = "moveIn";
function moveIn(e) : void
{
    var tweenUp: Tween = new Tween(e.currentTarget, "y", None.easeNone, -125, -900, .5, true);
    var tweenOver: Tween = new Tween(e.currentTarget, "x", None.easeNone, -125, 200, .1, true);
    var tweenDown: Tween = new Tween(e.currentTarget, "y", Elastic.easeOut, -900, 75, 2, true);
    var toyscaleX: Tween = new Tween(e.currentTarget, "scaleX", Elastic.easeOut, 0, 3, 2, true);
    var toyscaleY: Tween = new Tween(e.currentTarget, "scaleY", Elastic.easeOut, 0, 3, 2, true);
}


//Next Button Functionality

nextArrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goNext);
function goNext(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if (object1.y == 75) {
     object2[animateIn]();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you explain more what are you doing ? Are you trying to pass `object2` to `moveIn()`, or `moveIn()` is a function of `object2` which you try to call ?

Comment: Yes, i want moveIn() to be a function of object2 when the nextArrow is clicked, but only when object 1 is at a y position of 75.

Comment: You can not do that. Could you explain why you need that or what are you trying to do with that ? Are you trying to apply the tweens to `object2` ? ...

Comment: Yes, i have many more objects i will need to apply the same set of tweens to each time the next arrow is clicked. My motive is to do this in a way so that  the tweens wont freeze up or crash the program due to GC

Comment: I don't know why you are using an `Event` object as a param for your `moveIn()`  function, but you can do : `moveIn(object2)` after changing the type of that param of course ...

Comment: Would this allow me to recycle the same function for object3, object4.... object28, etc?  Just trying to avoid replicating those tween var over an over in the code.  Doing so caused the tweening to freeze up on my previous attempts at this. Can you provide a small example of how moveIn(object2) should look in the code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for example use the `moveIn()` function inside a class which will be instantiated to create all your objects :

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.transitions.easing.*;

    public class MyObject extends MovieClip {       

        public function MyObject() {
            // constructor code
        }

        public function moveIn() : void
        {
            var tweenUp: Tween = new Tween(this, "y", None.easeNone, -125, -900, .5, true);
            var tweenOver: Tween = new Tween(this, "x", None.easeNone, -125, 200, .1, true);
            var tweenDown: Tween = new Tween(this, "y", Elastic.easeOut, -900, 75, 2, true);
            var toyscaleX: Tween = new Tween(this, "scaleX", Elastic.easeOut, 0, 3, 2, true);
            var toyscaleY: Tween = new Tween(this, "scaleY", Elastic.easeOut, 0, 3, 2, true);
        }

    }

}
```

To create that class :

[image]

then you have just to call it using :

```
object2.moveIn();
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: This helps a lot, but is not working i think because I am trying to do this within a nested movie clip.

Comment: @Warren It's the class of your MovieClip ( ActionScript linkage class ). I edited my answer, take a look.

Comment: Not sure what i am doing wrong, but i keep getting erros that the class cannot be nested. I tried removing the 'package' part and still get nesting erros.

Comment: @Warren You've probably added the code on the timeline, which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use TweenMax, [by GreenSock](https://greensock.com/tweenmax-as):

Download the greensock.SWC library, put in near your .fla. Add the SWC by going to

*Advance Actionscript 3.0 Settings -> Library Path -> add SWC file*.

On the stage, I've put 5 movieclips named *object1* through *object5* and a SimpleButton named *button*.

[image]

This is de AS3 on the Timeline (F9):

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import com.greensock.TweenMax;

// array of all tweenable movieclips
var words:Array = [object1, object2,object3,object4,object5];

// animate first word to center
var currentWord:MovieClip = words[0];
animateCurrentWordToCenter();

// listen for button clicks
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickedHandler);


function buttonClickedHandler(event: MouseEvent): void 
{
  // get index
  var index:int = words.indexOf(currentWord);   

  // animate back to position
  var newY:Number = (index + 1) * 50;
  TweenMax.to(currentWord, 0.3, {x:20, y:newY, scaleX:1, scaleY:1});

  // calculate next index, loop back to first word 
  var nextIndex:int = (index + 1) % words.length;
  currentWord = words[nextIndex];

  // animate currentWord to center
  animateCurrentWordToCenter();
}

function animateCurrentWordToCenter()
{
  // syntax: TweenMax.to(<movieclip>, <duration>, <objectWithNewProperties>)
  TweenMax.to(currentWord, 0.3, {x:150, y:200, scaleX:2, scaleY:2});
}
```

You might want to save the original X,Y positions before animating the word to the center, and reset them when you animate them back, instead of what I did, calculate the Y using the index *(newY)* :P